# Mailchimp api how to get member source

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I need to find out which user added to list manual, or via api.
We are using v3 api of Mailchimp. 
With members endpoint

```
POST /lists/{list_id}/members
```

We get info about members, but there is no way to get a source.
So how get members source parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is still relevant, but might be helpful for others, so here's my findings:

If you have any platform passing this information back to MailChimp via the API into one of the [merge fields](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/merge-fields/), then that's the field to dig for in members.

The built-in source corresponds with the one you can see under the email address on the profile page of your list members. This is NOT passed through the API, so you can't export it that way, however, there is a lengthy workaround: You can create a segment for each of the Signup Sources either via the GUI from the tool or via the [API](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/segments/) (*look for POST /lists/{list_id}/segments and then under Request body parameters it's options/conditions/condition type next to Segment Type there is a dropdown, there you can select Signup Source Segment - Signup Source*), extract the segments into csv files, add the corresponding static Source (as per the segment criteria), and there, you have a lookup.

Below is the explanation to some of the fields. These are the ones we're using, and since it's not documented (*see [here](https://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/segments/all-the-segmenting-options), look for **Signup Source** further down the page*), I got this chatting to their Customer Service team:

*"**Admin Add**" > means contact was manually added using the "Add Contacts" > "Add a Contact" page in your list.*

*"**API Generic**" means that the contact was added by an API enabled form or by an API sync with a database.*

*"**Embed form**" means the contact was added using the embedded form code from your list. This can be found in the "Signup Forms" > "Embedded form code" section of your list.*

*"**Hosted Signup Form**" means the contact was added using the hosted signup form. This can be found in the "Signup Forms" > "Form Builder" section of your list.*

*"**List Import**" means contact was added via a list import.
"Unknown" means that we don't have a really clear understanding of how the contact was added to your list.*

There are a lot more types, if you go online and chat to their team, they will be able to tell you more about any that may not be self-explanatory.

Hope this helpZ? :)